# Opengl Texture Mapping of GL_QUADS, got strange result

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I got very strange result with texture mapping.

I used 128*128 RGBA bmp image to do texture mapping of a `GL_QUADS`, then I got the following strange result, test with other images are OK, but for this image, I got very strange result.

Here I want to map a leaf image to a `GL_QUADS`.

The following is my code:

```
void init (void)
{

glClearColor(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.0);
glClearDepth(1.0);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);



glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_CROSSHAIR);
}

void display(){

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity ();
gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

GLuint texture[2];

unsigned int outWidth;
unsigned int outHeight;
unsigned int outDepth;

glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

unsigned char * data=loadbmp("leaftest.bmp", outWidth, outHeight, outWidth, true);

gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, outWidth, outHeight, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 2);
    glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,-0.6,-0.3);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,-0.3);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,0.3);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,-0.6,0.3);

    glEnd();
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a picture? Off the top of my head I would guess the order of your uv coordinates is wrong.

Comment: Hi Justin: I am sorry but it did not allow me to add pictures here. The picture to be mapped is an image of a leaf. But I got a nearly blank texture with something green, which did not look like any part of the leaf.

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe because you do

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

before binding *any* texture target, this is plainly wrong and i wounder why some examples could work.

Check out some tutorials before you guys code, for example [this](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse872/tutorial4.html) or buy a book or something.